# my code for posting photos with ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, form-data

The code I wrote works in function, but not in button click. help me. it works if i write like below:

```
 function fotoSecti(inputId) {

    var inp = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var fil = inp.files;
    var formDat = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != fil.length; i++) {
        formDat.append("files", fil[i]);
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: odemeSecenekleriFotoEkle,
        data: formDat,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {...

}
```

but it doesn't work if i write it here:

```
$("#butonOdemeSecenekleriKaydet").click(function () {
var inp = document.getElementById("odemeSecenekleriInputFoto");
var fil = inp.files;
var formDat = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i != fil.length; i++) {
    formDat.append("files", fil[i]);
}



$.ajax({
        url: odemeSecenekleriFotoEkle,
        data: formDat,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {...
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> odemeSecenekleriKayit(List<IFormFile> files)
```

When I click the button, I want the data to go to the controller. the code is the same code. While the above function works, for some reason button.click does not work either.

html codes:

```
<form id="formOdemeSecenekleri" name="form" style="display:none;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input onchange="fotoSecti();" class="form-control" type="file" id="odemeSecenekleriInputFoto" style="width:250px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control odemeSecenekleriInput" placeholder="12 Taksit" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 butonDivOdemeSecenekleri">
                        <button id="butonOdemeSecenekleriKaydet" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Kaydet</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What is the error message you get when you click the button?

Comment: What type of button is that?

Comment: @Musa not error. As I said in the question, the data does not go to the controller. returns null. I also added the html codes of the question. you can look

Comment: @NitheeshGovind not error. As I said in the question, the data does not go to the controller. returns null. I also added the html codes of the question. you can look

Answer (score 0):

The button you're using is a submit button, that submits the form instead of doing ajax.
In your button event handler, you have to stop the form from submitting. You can do this by preventing the default action of the button with `event.preventDefault`

```
$("#butonOdemeSecenekleriKaydet").click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

or you can use a plain button instead of a submit button

```
<button type="button" id="butonOdemeSecenekleriKaydet" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Kaydet</button>
```